# Effect plot - Fixed Effects

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am using the MASS package to run a negative binomial regression model on count data. About half of my level 1 (countries) has 0 as outcome across all observations. Hence, there is no within-subject variation in the outcome. 
I want to plot the effect of the fitted values using the (effects) package in R.
However, when using a fixed effects model, studying only within subject I cannot manage to understand how the effects function plots the fitted values. If I simply tries to plot the fitted values for the fixed effects model, it will average out, and fail to show the effect (which probably have to be plotted for one "level 1" at the time.

I assume this is because I have to specify the given.values or xlevels for the effect function, to plot the effect for a specific level 1 unit, but I still have not managed to make it work.

I can easily plot the effect for a non-fixed effect model, but I would really appreciate if anyone could help me understand how to make the effect function work with fixed effect. Thanks!

```
# Set Seed
set.seed(123)
# Create test data, z being the level 1 subjects
testdat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n= 400), y=rep(c(2,0,0,0,1,2,5,0,0,0),40),    z=as.factor(rep(seq(1,10),40)))
#Load MASS and run fixed-effects
library(MASS)
nbmod <- glm.nb(y ~ x + z-1, data=testdat)
summary(nbmod)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = y ~ x + z - 1, data = testdat, init.theta = 42072.15381, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  2.98e-08  

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
x   -8.157e-17  5.308e-02   0.000        1    
z1   6.931e-01  1.125e-01   6.159 7.31e-10 ***
z2  -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
z3  -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
z4  -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
z5  -1.563e-16  1.581e-01   0.000        1    
z6   6.931e-01  1.123e-01   6.170 6.83e-10 ***
z7   1.609e+00  7.072e-02  22.759  < 2e-16 ***
z8  -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
z9  -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
z10 -2.830e+01  1.342e+05   0.000        1    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(42072.15) family taken to be 1)
#Plot effect display for fixed effect
library(effects)
plot(effect(term = "x", mod = nbmod))
#Run and plot non-fixed effect model
nbmod2 <- glm.nb(y ~ x, data=testdat)
plot(effect(term = "x", mod = nbmod2))
```

Comment: You need to look at your model (which is why I added the output from summary). The std errors being in the 10^5 range is a sign of a pathological fit. You don't need plotting advice. You need statistical education.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. A fixed model is used when the interest lies in the within unit variance. The fixed effects "controls" for the unobserved effects within unit (level 1). In this case, the neg.bin model is used to model the event (i.e. crime events) across boroughs within cities. Cities is level 1 and boroughs level 2. Some cities such as z2, z3 etc. does not have any crime within their boroughs, not contributing to the average.